# Copy and pasted Microsoft example of Javascript to check value in cell, but fails to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have been staring at the code below for hours, and I am not sure where to begin on how to fix the problem.  In advance, I believe this is more of a javascript problem on my end then a Microsoft Web API problem, since I am literally copying and pasting their code.

I am trying to use Microsoft Excel's Web API to embed an excel sheet on my web page (which works fine) . More specifically, I am trying to have, when highlighted on a cell, it display the value of the selected cell in an alert javascript box.

Here is their working example with code of exactly what I am trying to do  http://www.excelmashup.com/APIBrowser#example105

Simply change the tab from "Output" to "HTML" in the bottom right to see the same code as below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://r.office.microsoft.com/r/rlidExcelWLJS?v=1&kip=1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // run the Excel load handler on page load
    if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent("onload", loadEwaOnPageLoad);
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadEwaOnPageLoad, false);
    }

    function loadEwaOnPageLoad() {
      var fileToken = "SDBBABB911BCD68292!110/-4923638281765748078/t=0&s=0&v=!ALTlXd5D3qSGJKU";
      var props = {
              uiOptions: {
                    showGridlines: false,
          selectedCell: "'Sheet1'!C9",
                    showRowColumnHeaders: false,
                    showParametersTaskPane: false
              },
              interactivityOptions: {
                    allowTypingAndFormulaEntry: false,
                    allowParameterModification: false,
                    allowSorting: false,
                    allowFiltering: false,
                    allowPivotTableInteractivity: false
              }
      };
      Ewa.EwaControl.loadEwaAsync(fileToken, "myExcelDiv", props, onEwaLoaded);     
    }
    function onEwaLoaded() {
        document.getElementById("loadingdiv").style.display = "none";
    }
    // This sample gets the value in the highlighted cell. 
// Try clicking on different cells then running the sample.
function execute()
{
    // Get unformatted range values (getValuesAsync(1,...) where 1 = Ewa.ValuesFormat.Formatted)
    ewa.getActiveWorkbook().getActiveCell().getValuesAsync(1,getRangeValues,null);
}     

function getRangeValues(asyncResult)
{
    // Get the value from asyncResult if the asynchronous operation was successful.
    if (asyncResult.getCode() == 0)
    {
        // Get the value in active cell (located at row 0, column 0 of the
        // range which consists of a single cell (the "active cell")).
        alert("Result: " + asyncResult.getReturnValue()[0][0]);
    }
    else 
    {
          alert("Operation failed with error message " + asyncResult.getDescription() + ".");
    }    
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="execute();">Execute Sample</input> <<<<<Here is the problem
    <div id="myExcelDiv" style="width: 402px; height: 346px"></div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

When I change the above to onclick="alert('hello')" that works fine, but it does not alert the value of the cell when I use execute(); .  Maybe someone could copy and past the code into an .html file and see if it is just a problem on my end and whether the Microsoft code works for them.  If it does not work, that would also be useful information.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: The only error I receive is this - Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.http://wacsysnet.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/Scripts/TestHarness.js   However, I receive that both on my own copy & pasted version as well as the official microsoft site, and the code appears to function properly on the microsoft site - so I do not believe that is the problem.   If you copy either the above or directly from the microsoft link provided into an html file you will be able to see.  Truly appreciate any help

Comment: Doesn't work. First of all, I got a `ReferenceError: ewa is not defined`. Replaced wrong `ewa` for `Ewa`. Now I get `TypeError: Ewa.getActiveWorkbook is not a function`. Tested in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The key lays on the variable "ewa". Normally when the page loads, inside `loadEwaOnPageLoad()` there is this line: `Ewa.EwaControl.loadEwaAsync(fileToken, "myExcelDiv", props, onEwaLoaded);`  So we need to grab an Ewa object inside the onEwaLoaded function. I saw it somewhere like this (ewa declared somewhere else):

```
function onEwaLoaded(asyncResult) {
        /*
         * Add code here to interact with the embedded Excel web app.
         * Find out more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh315812.aspx.
         */

        if (asyncResult.getSucceeded()) {
            // Use the AsyncResult.getEwaControl() method to get a reference to the EwaControl object
            ewa = asyncResult.getEwaControl();

          //...
```

After you got the ewa object the rest would be fine. Without it then the variable ewa is indeed not defined.

Answer (score 0):

*The Excel Interactive View feature has been disabled.* However, I've just fixed some parts of your code to make it work. **I've put all details in the comments with asterisks**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://r.office.microsoft.com/r/rlidExcelWLJS?v=1&kip=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ewa = null;//*******************ADDING THIS IS BETTER**************************

        // run the Excel load handler on page load
        if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onload", loadEwaOnPageLoad);
        } else {
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadEwaOnPageLoad, false);
        }

        function loadEwaOnPageLoad() {
            var fileToken = "SDBBABB911BCD68292!110/-4923638281765748078/t=0&s=0&v=!ALTlXd5D3qSGJKU";
            var props = {
                uiOptions: {
                    showGridlines: false,
                    selectedCell: "'Sheet1'!C9",
                    showRowColumnHeaders: false,
                    showParametersTaskPane: false
                },
                interactivityOptions: {
                    allowTypingAndFormulaEntry: false,
                    allowParameterModification: false,
                    allowSorting: false,
                    allowFiltering: false,
                    allowPivotTableInteractivity: false
                }
            };
            Ewa.EwaControl.loadEwaAsync(fileToken, "myExcelDiv", props, onEwaLoaded);
        }
        function onEwaLoaded(asyncResult) { //*******************PASS asyncResult PARAMETER**************************

            //*******************THERE IS NO SUCH THING CALLED "loadingdiv"**************************
            //document.getElementById("loadingdiv").style.display = "none";

            //*******************ADD THIS IF-ELSE STATMENT**************************
            if (asyncResult.getSucceeded()) {
                // Use the AsyncResult.getEwaControl() method to get a reference to the EwaControl object
                alert("Async operation Succeeded!");
                ewa = asyncResult.getEwaControl();

            }
            else {
                alert("Async operation failed!");
            }
        }
        // This sample gets the value in the highlighted cell. 
        // Try clicking on different cells then running the sample.
        function execute() {
            // Get unformatted range values (getValuesAsync(1,...) where 1 = Ewa.ValuesFormat.Formatted)
            ewa.getActiveWorkbook().getActiveCell().getValuesAsync(1, getRangeValues, null);
        }

        function getRangeValues(asyncResult) {
            // Get the value from asyncResult if the asynchronous operation was successful.
            if (asyncResult.getCode() == 0) {
                // Get the value in active cell (located at row 0, column 0 of the
                // range which consists of a single cell (the "active cell")).
                alert("Result: " + asyncResult.getReturnValue()[0][0]);
            }
            else {
                alert("Operation failed with error message " + asyncResult.getDescription() + ".");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- *******************THE SIMICOLON AFTER execute() IS REMOVED*********************** -->
    <input type="button" onclick="execute()" value="Execute Sample"></input>
    <!-- *******************STYLE IS IMPROVED*********************** -->
    <div id="myExcelDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).